# How to hide the Minimap in Brackets?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I accidentally turned it on, I don't know how to hide it

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using [minimap plugin](https://github.com/zorgzerg/brackets-minimap). As you can see from the documentation:

> To show or hide the minimap, in the toolbar click View > Show Minimap
>   or press Ctrl+`.

Comment: thanks, but I don't see 'Show Minimap' in the toolbar

Comment: Is there anything regarding minimap in the View menu? Does `Ctrl+\`` work for you?